# min and max of input array file (.dat) with subroutine

Tags: arrays, io, fortran, fortran90

I try to implement a code that read in a number n, creates a vector to store n double precision numbers, read this number, call a subroutine printminmax() to find min and max. My code work perfect for normal numbers (integer,real etc) but when i have scientific notation (0.3412E+01) stack.Why? I thought with * read all the formats. Thanks

```
implicit none

integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: x
    integer :: n

    open (unit=77, file='input2.dat', action='read', status='old')
    read(77,*), n
    allocate(x(n))

    call printminmax(n)

    deallocate(x)

    end 

 subroutine printminmax(y)

implicit none

integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: x
integer :: y,max,min,i
   allocate(x(y))
   read(77,*) x
   !print *,'Maximun=', maxval(x)

   !print *,'Minimun=', minval(x

   !initialize the value max & min
max=x(1)
min=x(1)
do i=2,y
    if (x(i)>max) max=x(i)
    if (x(i)<min) min=x(i)
end do
    write(*,*) 'Maximum=',max
write(*,*) 'Minimum=',min

    end subroutine printminmax
```

one example of the stack input is

```
  1000
  5.39524398466520e-01
  9.85099770130787e-01
  7.38946122872518e-01
  6.47771620257608e-01
  8.80871051119695e-01
  2.99375585725816e-02
```

the error that i take for scientific notation is

```
   At line 13 of file io.f90 (unit = 77, file = 'input3.dat')
   Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input
```

Comment: sorry!there is an integer in the first line. This number is 1000

Comment: The problem as i understand is with the read()

Answer (score 0):

ok i found it.I should have double precision on x, no integer.

Comment: Yes, your problem was that you were trying to put an integer where you read a double precision number.